# how can i convert my users profiles URL to subDomain with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

how can i convert my users profiles URL to subDomain
with htaccess

I tried used this code in htaccess but it's not work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(iemg\.net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Like : http://iemg.net/usersprofile.php?username=mohamed to http://mohamed.iemg.net

Comment: Please include the original URL and the URL you wish to rewrite into. It makes it easier to debug.

Comment: the code has been updated

Answer (score 0):

First, you must capture the user part of the domain, and then use this in the substitution

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.iemg\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://iemg.net/usersprofile.php?username=%1 [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: i was added your code into my htaccess file and when i enter to this path 

[link](http://username11.iemg.net/) 
found this error
`"This site can’t be reached
username11.iemg.net’s server DNS address could not be found.
"`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the rewrite rule. You must setup your DNS addresses, of course, before this can work. You need to setup your Apache's virtual host config to serve these domains also. A wildcard DNS entry should work as well.